# Manual Testing Interview Questions

Tags: ros, ros2

I'm preparing for a manual testing interview and I'm looking for some help with the following questions:

What are the different types of software testing?
Explain functional testing.
Explain non-functional testing.
Mention a few advantages of automated testing.
What is regression testing?
What is test harness?
Differentiate between positive and negative testing.
I've found a helpful resource with a list of [manual testing interview questions and answers](https://www.interviewbit.com/manual-testing-interview-questions/).

Do you have any tips or advice for answering these questions?

Thanks in advance for your help!